# Distributing widths of a group of objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Say I have a set of 5 MovieClips with same y locations but spread out x locations in ascending order (e.g `obj1.x = 0`, `obj5.x = 10`), is there an AS3 method that helps me distribute their widths like the option under *Modify* > *Align* in flash, so their x locations are equally spaced between 0 and 10?

Thanks

Comment: So you want all their widths to be the same? or you want them all to have the same amount of space/gap between each item but with their native width?

Comment: My answers assumes the latter, but I'm not sure if that's what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote many years ago that you may find useful.  It assumes that the things you want to space out are the sole children of a parent/container. You pass that parent to this function as the first parameter (displayObj).  Hopefully the comments at the start explain to you well enough what each parameter does, if not just comment and I'll clarify.

```
/**
* Distribte all the children of the specified display object on either x or  y axis
* @param    displayObj - the display oject whose children should be distributed
* @param    onX - should it distribute along the x axis (true) or the y axis (false)
* @param    spacing - how much space between children in pixels
* @param    center - should the children be centered on the opposite axis
* @param    startingX - default 0
* @param    startingY - default 0
* @param    fixedWidth - use a fixed width instead the automatic width of each child
* @param    foldPoint - how far along before the item should fold and be a new row/col
*/
public static function distributeAxis(displayObj:Sprite,onX:Boolean = true,spacing:Number = 5, center:Boolean = false, startingX:Number = 0,startingY:Number = 0,fixedWidth:Number = 0, foldPoint:Number = 0):void {

    //Loop Through Children
        var tObj:DisplayObject;
        var tNum    :Number = (onX) ?   startingX   : startingY;
        var tNum2   :Number = (onX) ?   startingY   : startingX;
        var max     :Number = 0;

        var centeringArray:Vector.<DisplayObject>
        if (center) {
            centeringArray = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
        }

        for(var i:int = 0; i<displayObj.numChildren;i++)
        {
            tObj = displayObj.getChildAt(i);

            if (onX) {
                if (foldPoint > 0 && tNum + tObj.width > foldPoint) {
                    tNum = startingX;
                    tNum2 += max + spacing;

                    if(center){
                        distributeAxisCenterIt(centeringArray, max, onX);
                        centeringArray = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
                    }

                    max = 0;
                }

                if(tObj.height > max) max = tObj.height;

                tObj.x = tNum;
                tObj.y = tNum2;

                if(fixedWidth > 0){
                    tNum += fixedWidth + spacing;
                }else{
                    tNum += tObj.width + spacing;
                }

                if(center){
                    centeringArray.push(tObj);
                }

            }else{
                if(tObj.width > max) max = tObj.width;

                if (foldPoint > 0 && tNum + tObj.height > foldPoint) {
                    tNum = startingY;
                    tNum2 += max + spacing;

                    if(center){
                        distributeAxisCenterIt(centeringArray, max, onX);
                        centeringArray = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
                    }
                    max = 0;
                }

                tObj.y = tNum;
                tObj.x = tNum2;

                if(fixedWidth > 0){
                    tNum += fixedWidth + spacing;
                }else{
                    tNum += tObj.height + spacing;
                }

                if(center){
                    centeringArray.push(tObj);
                }
            }

        }


    if (center) {
        distributeAxisCenterIt(centeringArray, max, onX);
    }
}

private static function distributeAxisCenterIt(array:Vector.<DisplayObject>, max:Number, onX:Boolean = true):void {
                for each(var tObj:DisplayObject in array){
                    if(onX){
                        tObj.y += ((max - tObj.height) * .5);
                    }else{
                        tObj.x += ((max - tObj.width) * .5);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this: [AS3 Commons UI](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/). It has all you could ever want:) with layout/align etc. and components

but if you want a code not a framework this is what I'm using for spreading items across given width in my own "framework":

```
    /**
     * Distributes all components using given value as a limit.
     * @param   p_nMaxWidth width of the area to spread items
     */
    protected function spreadComponents(p_nMaxWidth:Number):void
    {
        if (numChildren == 0) return;

        if (p_nMaxWidth < 0 || isNaN(p_nMaxWidth)) p_nMaxWidth = 600;
        var _oItem:DisplayObject;
        var dx:Number = 0;
        var i:int;
        var _nWidth:Number = calculateWidths();//get sum of all items widths
        var _nStep:Number = (p_nMaxWidth - _nWidth - getChildAt(numChildren - 1).width) / (numChildren-1);
        for (i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
        {
            _oItem = getChildAt(i);
            //if(m_bResetChildrenPosition) _oItem.y = 0;//this I was using to reset or keep intact the items y position
            _oItem.x = Math.round(dx);
                dx += _oItem.width + _nStep;
        }
        //as a precaution if rounding would give incorrect position (which should be for last item exactly at the p_nMaxWidth - width (right edge aligned)).
        getChildAt(numChildren - 1).x = p_nMaxWidth - getChildAt(numChildren - 1).width;

        updateDimension();
    }


//
    /**
     * Utility method, returns width of all children (sum).
     * @return
     */
    protected function calculateWidths():Number
    {
        var _nWidth:Number = 0;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren-1; i++)
            {
                _nWidth += getChildAt(i).width;
            }
        return _nWidth;
    }
```

this code spreads items horizontaly across given width - left edge of first item is at start, right edge of last item is at the end of that "width".

best regards

Comment: of course to make it vertically spread is trivial:) just change widths to heights x to y where appriopriate:)

Comment: if you only want to spread equaly origin points exluding items size than all you need to do is divide your width by the amount of items to spread and then in a loop add this calculated step to each item.